# Export in tilde delimited

Tags: excel, vba

I first create files in Excel. This macro saves all sheets into separate tab delimited text files.

How can I save with a tilde "~" instead of a tab?

```
Sub newworkbooks()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, SheetName$, MyFilePath$, N&
    MyFilePath$ = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
    Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
         '      End With
        On Error Resume Next '<< a folder exists
        MkDir MyFilePath '<< create a folder
        For N = 1 To Sheets.Count
            Sheets(N).Activate
            SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
            Cells.Copy
            Workbooks.Add (xlWBATWorksheet)
            With ActiveWorkbook
                With .ActiveSheet
                    .Paste
                    .Name = SheetName
                    [A1].Select
                End With
                 'save book in this folder
                .saveas Filename:=MyFilePath _
                & "\PO" & SheetName & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
                .Close SaveChanges:=True
            End With
            .CutCopyMode = False
        Next
    End With
    Sheet1.Activate

End Sub
```

Instead of looking like the following

```
this   is   a   test
```

it should look like this

```
this~is~a~test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach, which would be easy to modify to suit - this gives you control over the character set and the delimiter:

https://excel.solutions/2014/04/using-vba-write-excel-data-to-text-file/

```
Sub WriteTextFile()

Dim rng As Range, lRow As Long
Dim stOutput As String, stNextLine As String, stSeparator As String
Dim stFilename As String, stEncoding As String
Dim fso As Object

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'CHANGE THESE PARAMETERS TO SUIT
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'this is the range which will be written to text file
stFilename = "C:\Temp\TextOutput.txt" 'this is the text file path / name
stSeparator = vbTab 'e.g. for comma seperated value, change this to ","
stEncoding = "UTF-8" 'e.g. "UTF-8", "ASCII"
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For lRow = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        stNextLine = rng.Rows(lRow).Value
    Else
        stNextLine = Join$(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Rows(lRow).Value)), stSeparator)
    End If
    If stOutput = "" Then
        stOutput = stNextLine
    Else
        stOutput = stOutput & vbCrLf & stNextLine
    End If
Next lRow

Set fso = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With fso
    .Type = 2
    .Charset = stEncoding
    .Open
    .WriteText stOutput
    .SaveToFile stFilename, 2
End With
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm sure you could adapt that to loop through your worksheets, and output the UsedRange of each.

**EDIT:**

Here's how to adapt it to use tilde as separator, and loop through each worksheet;

```
Sub OutputAllSheetsTildeSeparated()

    Dim rng As Range, lRow As Long
    Dim stOutput As String, stNextLine As String, stSeparator As String
    Dim stFilepath As String, stFilename As String, stEncoding As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object

    stFilepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)
    stSeparator = "~"
    stEncoding = "UTF-8"

    If Dir(stFilepath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then MkDir stFilepath

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set rng = ws.UsedRange
        stFilename = stFilepath & "\PO" & ws.Name & ".txt"

        For lRow = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            If rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then
                stNextLine = rng.Rows(lRow).Value
            Else
                stNextLine = Join$(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Rows(lRow).Value)), stSeparator)
            End If
            If stOutput = "" Then
                stOutput = stNextLine
            Else
                stOutput = stOutput & vbCrLf & stNextLine
            End If
        Next lRow

        Set fso = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        With fso
            .Type = 2
            .Charset = stEncoding
            .Open
            .WriteText stOutput
            .SaveToFile stFilename, 2
        End With
        Set fso = Nothing

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, how can I change the tab separator for tilde
you use stSeparator = vbTab 

for tilde it should be stSeparator = ~?

Additionally, the macro I use exports all sheets to a separate txt file and uses the sheet name for file name adding "PO" at the beginning

Comment: I've edited my answer to show one way of doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks Olly. this is exactly what I'm looking for. I modified the code to start at row 2. 

Thanks again, you helped great deal

Comment: This is a beneficial script, thanks guys.  One of my columns has 5-digit US zip codes in it, which can often contain leading zeros that need to remain in the data upon export.  Currently, this script exports a file that does not retain the leading zeros that exist on-screen in excel.  Is there a modifier or setting I can adjust in this script to retain those zeros?